Controlling Checkbox Behavior
My UserForm has several checkboxes representing possible options to  the user. When any one is “checked”, a “_Click() procedure correctly executes my code.  But I also want to clear all remaining checkboxes in the process.
When a previously checked box is cleared by code, its change of state from “checked” -> “unchecked” triggers another involuntary “_Click()” procedure.
Is there a way of disabling a “_Click()” procedure from being run?

You need to use a flag to "short-circuit" the events.

I advise looking into 'Option Button and Frames' in Excel or 'Option Group and Option Button' in Access depending on where you are designing your forms.
They together have the functionality you are describing.

I chose checkboxes because when any one is checked, I can display specific instructions to the user. I don’t want to have the user “uncheck” any boxes.

Yes, so when an option button is clicked the 'Frame' or 'OptionGroup' will have its value alerted to the corresponding button value, which is where your logic will come into place. All while all other options values get 'Unchecked'
